# TypeScript 4 - property find does not exist on type number[]

Tags: typescript

I am learning TypeScript and I have got version 4.0.5 installed. My problem is that i have variable with array of numbers:

```
const arrayOfNumbers: number[] = [];
```

And later I am pushing some numbers into it and later I want to find some numbers inside.

```
arrayOfNumbers.find(el => el === index)
```

Which throws me an error:

> Property 'find' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

But on intellisense I can see find method.

Comment: Your code example works fine in TS playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your tsconfig to target ES2015 or above.

For single file compilations

```
tsc {filepath} --lib es6
```

You can reproduce the error here:
[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngeQGYDkCuBbAIwFMEIAuGMfYhAbQF0YBeGWgJgBoBmDgFg4Cs9ALAAoMYmTps1EhAB0GAJZgAJgApOXAJRA)

Comment: I have set target to es6 and compile error has gone but I cannot transpile code to js because I am getting the same error as above

Comment: can you confirm that if you have tsconfig.build.json it does not override the target property. Your tsc command should respect the config file

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with tsc compiler. When I want to transplie ts file by using filename:

```
tsc index.ts
```

It ignores tsconfig.json. When I transplie simply with:

```
tsc
```

An error has gone and I can use now find method from ES6

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29473#issuecomment-455601893

Comment: tsc {filepath} --lib es6

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following line to your

```
tsconfig.json file:"lib": ["e2015"]
```

After this you may face console.log () error for this if your code is running in a browser environment, you need to add “Dom” to the lib array in your tsconfig.json file, which tells the compiler to include the type definitions for built-in JavaScript APIs found in browser environments, such as the console object. For example:

```
"lib": [
      // other libs...
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
```